# Sorting files by creation day

Tags: powershell

There is a report that runs every day (we only have the choice of daily or monthly) and we only need one day of the week to upload. I need to move the file created on Monday and delete all the other files in the directory.

I was able to get the creation time in one variable and then use another variable to extract the day of the week. This will only work for one file so I need to add the `foreach` statement to this process.

```
$FileDate = (Get-ChildItem "c:\temp\version.ps1").CreationTime
Write-Output $filedate

$day = (Get-Date $filedate).DayOfWeek

if ($day -eq "Monday") {
    Write-Output Correct file, copy to another directory
} else {
    Write-Host Delete file
}
```

The script only works for one file and not the entire directory. What I need to be able to do is look at the creation date of each file and if it's from Monday move it and all others are deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipeline your results to `foreach` to iterate over each file you retrieve, then perform the appropriate action:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\temp | foreach {

    $day = $_.CreationTime.DayOfWeek

    if ($day -eq "Monday") {
        Move-Item $_ $destination
    } else {
        Remove-Item $_
    }

}
```

Comment: I very much appreciate the help! When I run the script I am getting an error on the Get-Date statement:
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert the "snapshot_blob.bin" value of type 
"System.IO.FileInfo" to type "System.DateTime".
At line:3 char:22
+     $day = (Get-Date $_).DayOfWeek

I also changed the destination in a fashion I am hoping is correct:
Get-ChildItem c:\temp | foreach {

    $day = (Get-Date $_).DayOfWeek

    if ($day -eq "Monday") {
        Move-Item $_ -Destination 'C:\temp2'
    } else {
        Remove-Item $_
    }

}

Comment: @CaptainMike Sorry, made a small mistake. `Get-Date` won't work on a `FileInfo` object. Just use the `CreationTime` property instead. See my edit.

Comment: It's working now, Thank you again for everyone's help.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Where-Object` to filter for files not created on a particular day, then move them and remove the rest.

```cs
Get-ChildItem 'C:\temp' | Where-Object {
    $_.CreationTime.DayOfWeek -ne 'Monday'
} | Move-Item -Destination 'C:\somewhere\else\' -WhatIf
Remove-Item 'C:\temp\*.*' -WhatIf
```

Re-run without the `-WhatIf` switches after you verified that only the files you want will be moved and only the ones you want deleted will be deleted (the moved files will be also reported as being deleted, though, since they're not actually moved yet).

Comment: This will rather than keeping Monday files in place delete them, which is not the intention here, I suppose ;)

Comment: @StanislavCastek You're right. I misread the question. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: *<nitpick>* [DayOfWeek](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek?view=netframework-4.8) is not localized but that's something I had to look up. I'd prefer `DayOfWeek -eq [System.DayOfWeek]::Monday` and not have to wonder at all. *</nitpick>*